# approximating Lipschitz functions by polynomials?

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, approximation-theory

If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|\ $ for all $x$, $y\in[0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$ is fixed, why must there be a polynomial $p$ of degree less than $\frac{10}{\epsilon^3}$ such that $|f-p|_{\infty}<\epsilon$?

I've tried an $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$-type method, using $|f(x)-p(x)|\leq|p(x)-p(y)|+|p(y)-f(y)|+|x-y|$, but couldn't get good enough bounds on the RHS. Since $f$ must be (uniformly) continuous, maybe we could use Bernstein polynomials? Or does the peculiar bound on the degree give us a clue as to how to find a suitable $p$?

Many thanks for any help with this!

Comment: Try the Jackson's inequality, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson%27s_inequality

Comment: @vesszabo: Jackson's inequality only covers differentiable functions. The $f$ in this problem is only Lipschitz, not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: Jackson's inequality valid for continuous functions also (r=0) (Theorem 2.). The Lipschitz function is continuous. 
See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson%27s_inequality

Comment: @vesszabo: Sorry, you're right! +1 Jackson's inequality gives $p$ of degree at most $C_1(0)/\epsilon$ such that $|f-p|_{\infty}<\epsilon$. That's going to be a much stronger result than what I need. Is there a simpler way to prove it without using Jackson?

Comment: @vesszabo Your could write your comments in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ we can apply the Jackson's theorem which says
$$
|f(x)-P_n(x)|\leq C \omega\left( f,\frac{1}{n}\right),
$$
where $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ and $\omega(f,\delta)$ is the modulus of continuity of $f$. Here the sharp value of $C$ is known. More details can be found here https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Jackson_inequality. 
Using the Lipschitzian property of $f$ an estimation for the degree follows (if the error is controlled by $\varepsilon$).
If you want to avoid Jackson's theorem, then, you are right, the Bernstein polynomials can be used. By very elementary calculation gives that
$$
|f(x)-B_n(f,x)|\leq C \omega\left( f,\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right),
$$
see e.g. [www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387954844-c36.pdf](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387954844-c36.pdf) Theorem 36.4.

Comment: Do we know something about the coefficients of $P_n$? Specifically, I am interested in bounding the L1 norm of the coefficients vector